# Wrong index order when using \lstinline in \index

Tags: indexing, lstlisting

A stub of my document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter}
This is a\index{A} test\index{\lstinline{TEST}}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I am compiling with `pdflatex` and `makeindex`.

I would like to use `\lstinline{}` for formatting some keywords at the index. My problem is that there is a wrong order at the index. `TEST` is ordered before `A`.

Is there a way to achieve that `TEST` would be ordered the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong way to apply special formatting to an index. You need to use the `key@visual` syntax:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx,listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter}
This is a\index{A} test\index{TEST@\lstinline{TEST}}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]